# How to rewrite this ES6 code in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm very new to TypeScript. I find hard to rewrite some of my ES6 code to TypeScript.

For example, How can you rewrite this to typescript.

```
const actionTypes = [
  'SAMPLE',
]

export default actionTypes.reduce((obj, str) => {
  const mirror = {
    [str]: str,
  }
  return { ...obj, ...mirror }
}, {})
```

I tried this

```
const actionTypes: String[] = ['SAMPLE']


const map: Object = actionTypes.reduce((obj: Object, str: String) => {
  const mirror: Object = {
    [str]: str,
  }
  return Object.assign({}, obj, mirror)
}, {})
```

But, it throws error at `[str]: str`.

> [ts] A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.
>
> (parameter) str: String

What am I doing wrong? Does TS supports spread operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use generics:

```
function createMirror<T>(actionTypes: string[]) {
    let obj = {};
    actionTypes.forEach((str) => {
        const mirror = {
            [str]: str,
        }
        obj = Object.assign({}, obj, mirror);
    });
    return <T>obj;
};

interface MyActionTypes {
    SAMPLE: string
}

const myActionTypes = [
    'SAMPLE',
];

var map = createMirror<MyActionTypes>(myActionTypes);
```

If you use `Object.assign` you will lose the TypeScript benefits:

[image]

Comment: But if you have the knowledge on the content of `actionTypes` at compile time, then you should just declare the map: `const map = {SAMPLE: 'SAMPLE'}`. More concise.

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT: Rest / spread properties `{ ...obj, ...mirror }` [are now available](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2103) with TypeScript 2.1. See [your first code in the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20actionTypes%20%3D%20[%0D%0A%20%20%27SAMPLE%27%2C%0D%0A]%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20default%20actionTypes.reduce%28%28obj%2C%20str%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20mirror%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20[str]%3A%20str%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20return%20%7B%20...obj%2C%20...mirror%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%2C%20%7B%7D%29).*

---

The type `string` is with a lowercase "s". Do not use the type `Object`. You could use `{}` for the type of an empty object.

But, in your case, `actionTypes` is inferred as `string[]`. Then the parameters `obj` and `str` of the `reduce` function are inferred as `string` too.

```
const actionTypes = ['SAMPLE']
const map = actionTypes.reduce((obj, str) => {
  const mirror = {
    [str]: str,
  }
  return Object.assign({}, obj, mirror)
}, {})
```

Notice: Rest / spread properties `{ ...obj, ...mirror }` are not from ES6 but ES7.

---

The classic way with a `for of` loop is more expressive and with better performance:

```
const actionTypes = ['SAMPLE'],
      map = {}
for (const name of actionTypes)
  map[name] = name
```